# Creating infinite objects in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, python-3.5

I'm working on my very simple game project using python3 and pygame, one of my first might I add, and I'm trying to generate a block that falls down the screen every X seconds. The block is a class object (for multiple reasons), and I just can't grasp the concept of creating new objects and how to call their functions later on. I obviously can't just call 1000 objects with names of block1, block2, block3... and so on, so how do I deal with this problem?

This is a pretty simple game loop that I'm running:

```
player = Player()
block = Block()

gameExit = False
while not gameExit:
    dt = clock.tick(fps)
    timePassed += dt

    gameDisplay.fill(black)
    player.update()
    block.update()

    blockspawner = (4 / velocity) * 1000
    velocity += 0.001

    if timePassed > blockspawner:
        #this is where i'd create my new Block() object
        timePassed = 0

    pygame.display.update()
```

Is there a really simple solution to this problem that I haven't heard of yet?

Comment: `block` is a *class instance*, `Block` is a class object. (Classes *are* objects in Python, **everything** is an object).

Comment: But, I'm not sure what you mean by "create infinite objects". You *can't create infinite objects*. You only have finite memory, so number of objects is necessarily finite. I think you just need to use a *container*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'd say `itertools.repeat(0)` is an infinite object.

Comment: This question needs more help than we can provide. We like helping people, but sometimes you need to help yourself first by reading a book on the language, the on-line documentation, or asking someone you know. Once you understand the topic a little better, we invite you to edit this question, fix the obvious mistakes, and get it re-opened.

Comment: You've identified the basic problem: you don't yet know how to handle sequences, classes, objects, methods, et alia.  Find yourself useful tutorials on those topics.  Come back when you hit a more specific problem in your coding; we'll be here.

Comment: @StefanPochmann I suppose it is  a matter of semantics, but all I mean to say is that you cannot materialize an infinite number of objects into memory.   I do not think the OP was speaking of a non-terminating iterator anyway...

Comment: you can use a sprite group, and a while loop

Comment: I said infinite, but I really meant 'any given ammount of'. So I want, say, 10 objects on the screen at the same time. But then I might want 20 a second later. How do i create and manage all of them?

Comment: Anyway, if you say my knowledge is indeed not anywhere building that program, then I'll go back to reading and come back to this one later. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for creating infinite objects. Just create a list where you store your objects. Also you have to create some way to delete the Blocks that are not used anymore. One way is to check when the block is out from the screen and delete it or not visible to the user.

Comment: By infinite i really just meant 'any given amount'. How would I go about calling these functions later on? Let's say i want to call the self.update() function for every single one of them, or I want to call that function for one specific object in the list. Would it be list[0].update()?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an list of block objects.

```
block_list.append(Block())
```

Comment: And if I want to reference them, say, call the self.update() function, how would I do it?

Comment: That's what I thought, but it gives me the error of 
blockList[0].update()
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Doesn't matter where in the code I put it, if its in the loop it just returns this error.

Comment: @AdamKarolczak to update all blocks: `for block in block_list: block.update()`

Comment: The error sounds like block_list is empty, take care to define the list outside of the loop you use to add members to the list.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call `Block()`, it creates a new object. So put an object-creating statement like `block = Block()` inside your main loop, and you'll have unlimited new objects for as long as the loop runs. If it runs forever, you'll have "infinite" objects.

You'll need to do more work so you can have more than one object at a time. E.g., you can keep them on a list. Start out with the first block:

```
blocks = [ Block() ]
```

Now run the game. Whenever it's time for a new block to appear, add one to the end of the list. Blocks will accumulate until you start removing them. It's simplest if they all move at the same speed: When you detect that the oldest block (always at position 0) has left the screen area and must be discarded,  shift the list.

```
while not gameExit:
    # do game stuff, e.g. display and keeping track of screen positions

    if add_a_block:
        blocks.append(Block())

    if out_of_bounds(blocks[0]):
         blocks = blocks[1:]
```

How you decide when to add or remove a block is up to you. The example assumed a function `out_of_bounds()` that detects exit, but you can check coordinates directly or whatever.

Comment: Actually, having more than one at the time is exactly what I need to do here, so that's what I'd like to know.

Comment: Generate several, and put them in a list. Then create more in the loop as the game progresses. At some point of the loop, you also check if it's time to throw each block away.